# BBC micro:bit extension adding failed for Scratch

Tags: mit-scratch, bbc-microbit

I bought a new micro:bit v2 board, and want to add it to Scratch as an extension. I followed the 2 steps from https://scratch.mit.edu/microbit. The step 1 is ok, the led lights of my micro:bit board is flashing 5 characters "zepiv", but the step 2 failed.

[image]

The scratch link is running, and the bluetooth is enabled.

[image]

[image]

The os version is macOS Big sur 11.4(Mac mini late 2014), the bluetooth LMP version is 4.0(0x6).

The weird thing is that the board isn't visible to my Mac, but it is to my Android cell phone.

[image]

Is this a problem with my computer? Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a good sign that the micro:bit can be seen by your Android phone. Have you tried rebooting your mac and/or disabling and re-enabling Bluetooth?
If you have already Bluetooth connected the micro:bit to a compute or mobile, make sure you disconnect it and flash again the scratch hex file.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I had a lot of trouble with the same issue when connecting my LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3© to scratch. If you want to connect a device easily a good idea is to have it paired via Bluetooth already. To pair it with a mac:

1. Open the settings app
2. Select Bluetooth
3. Switch your micro:bit into pairing mode:

- Hold down buttons A and B on the front of your micro:bit together. The front is the side with two buttons and the LED display. Keep the two buttons held down. Don’t let go of them yet!
- While still holding down buttons A and B, press and then release the reset button on the back of the micro:bit. Keep holding down buttons A and B.
- You should see “PAIRING MODE!” start to scroll across the micro:bit display. When you see this message start to appear you can release buttons A and B.
- Eventually you’ll see a strange pattern on your micro:bit display. This is like your micro:bit’s signature. Other people’s micro:bits will probably display a different pattern.
  (I found these instructions at [this website](https://makecode.microbit.org/v0/reference/bluetooth/bluetooth-pairing))

4. In the Bluetooth menu, look for your micro:bit device and select `Pair`
5. After the device has paired, go back to scratch with scratch link activated, and attempt to connect to the device again.

This worked for me when I connected my EV3 device and I hope it helps you.